# Firebase auto check time sending data to server? Or i must create variable Time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want create app with Realtime. When i send data to sever, but my internet is slow. Same time, other users send data and it go to server first. Firebase will put my data first or other users first?

Comment: i think it depends of the kind of data you are sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to handle time with Firebase and which one you'll want to use depends on your use-case. If you want to "check who pressed a key on their device first", you'll want to use Firebase's `push()` method to generate keys. If on the other hand you want to detect who's data reached the database first, you'll want to use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

When a device/browser connects to the Firebase Realtime database, it detects the time offset between the client and the server. It then uses this value to estimate the server timestamp it uses to generate client-side `push()` IDs. So these provide a reasonable (but not secure, they can be faked by the client) way to estimate when an event happened according to the user's device.

When you use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` in your code, the client initially uses the same time offset to estimate the server-side timestamp. Then it sends the data to the server, which corrects the timestamp if needed. so with this approach you're guaranteed that the timestamp is exactly when the data was written into the database on the server.